# How to Create Cone Modification / Trunk

Tags: tikz-pgf

Simply, I want to create this image:
[image: 1]

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=0]
    \draw[violet, fill=violet!10] (4,0) arc(-45:225:4) -- (1.5,2) -- (4,0) node[left, black]{$l$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `scope` is your friend here. You can set options only for the drawing inside, as rotation, scale, origin, etc.

For example:

```tex
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\tikzset
{% styles
   my node/.style={midway,black},
   my violet/.style={violet,fill=violet!#1},
   my violet/.default=10,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round]
  % dimensions
  \def\r{4}  % radius
  \def\h{10} % height
  \pgfmathsetmacro\a{asin(\r/\h)}       % angle
  \pgfmathsetmacro\g{sqrt(\h*\h-\r*\r)} % generatrix
  % right figure
  \draw[my violet] (-45:\r)  arc (-45:225:\r) -- (0,0) -- cycle node[my node,below left] {$l$};
  \draw[-latex]    (-45:0.6) arc (-45:225:0.6)                  node[pos=0.35,above]     {$\theta$};
  % left figure
  \begin{scope}[shift={(-10,0)},y=0.5cm,rotate=-20,scale=0.9]
    \draw[my violet=20] (0,\h) --   (-70:\r)   arc (-70:250:\r)   -- cycle;
    \draw[my violet]    (0,\h) --++ (\a-90:\g) arc (\a:180-\a:\r) -- cycle node[my node,yshift=0.5cm] {$l$};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I made new friend now in Tikz, `scope`

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{bending}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick]
\filldraw[cyan, fill=cyan!20, rotate=-20, miter limit=1] (0,3) -- (-70:2 and 1) arc[x radius=2, y radius=1, start angle=-70, end angle=250] -- cycle;
\filldraw[cyan, fill=cyan!20, rotate=-20] (0,3) -- (20:2 and 1) arc[x radius=2, y radius=1, start angle=20, end angle=160] --node[black, above left]{$l$} cycle;
\filldraw[cyan, fill=cyan!20] (5,1) --node[black, pos=0.6, below left]{$l$} +(-40:2) arc[radius=2, start angle=-40, end angle=220] -- cycle;
\draw[-latex] (5,1) +(-40:0.6)  arc[radius=0.6, start angle=-40, end angle=220] node[pos=0.3, above right]{$\theta$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Folded cone and circle section]

Comment: I was thinking there are 2 people who always answer most of my TikZ problems. Are these two the last 2 man standing in LaTeX?

Comment: @Freya the Goddess: There are millions of LaTex users. There are thousands of people who answer LaTeX problems. Hundreds that answer TikZ problems. Tens that answer simple problems like yours. If you come back in a month or a year, maybe some other users are active.